# Ensime doesn't show source code of downloaded libraries

Tags: scala, emacs, ide, ensime

I'm currently a [happy user of emacs-ensime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626203/text-editor-for-scala). Wholly it's a good IDE but there is an issue - I can't view scaladoc when I choose some method of a class in type inspector. I use ivy for dependency management, it downloads libs that I need with source code and doc jars (sometimes only with docs/sources).

According to [ensime manual](http://aemon.com/file_dump/ensime_manual.html#tth_sEc4.9) it should work.

> If ENSIME cannot find the source for a type or member, it will instead try to browse to the www documentation.

Any suggestions why it can't find source and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ensime is in a very early state of its development and there a lot of bugs at this point. Aemon(the lead developer) is pretty fast to respond to all problems posted on the project's issue tracker at GitHub, so I'd suggest opening an issue [there](http://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime/issues).